# Django - relation with class model instances

Tags: django, django-models

I made some model classes with pets types: Parrot, Rabbit, Cat, Dog and i need make model
Shop, where one field will be related for few of this models. This field will show what sells in shop.
Can i make relation beetween one model object to few model classes?

If i can't, how i need change my scheme?

ex:

1 Shop1 [Parrot, Rabbit]

2 Shop2 [Cat, Dog, Rabbit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have created model classes representing different types of pets, and you want to associate individual shops with a number of those classes.

I'm assuming your pet model definitions look something like this:

```
class Parrot(models.Model):
    pining_for_fjords = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

You could do this using [`contenttypes`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Shop(models.Model):
    pet_types = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType)
```

---

```
parrot_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model="parrot")

// ManyToManyFields need to be added to already saved models
my_shop = Shop.objects.create()
my_shop.pet_types.add(parrot_type)
```